# How to add a swf file in cakephp theme?

Tags: php, cakephp, flash

i am making a theme for my cakephp project for that i having a template file and it include a cu3er slider for main page so I guess I need to change this file to php code guys please help me

```
swfobject.embedSWF("cu3er.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9",         "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);
```

i tried this but not working

```
swfobject.embedSWF("<? print $this->webroot . 'swf/cu3er.swf'?>, "cu3er-container", "960",    "400", "9", "<? print $this->webroot . 'swf/expressInstall.swf'?>", flashvars, attributes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use App::themePath($theme) to get your theme's path, then do whatever you want from there.

So a file in:

```
app/views/themed/my_theme/webroot/swf/my_flash_file.swf
```

Could be grabbed via:

```
App::themePath('my_theme').'webroot'.DS.'swf'.DS.'my_flash_file.swf';
```

Comment: Hai Nirav Ranpara I tried this but this is not what I looking for

if I added this to my code it will get the HTML output like this
    swfobject.embedSWF("<? print App::themePath('my_theme').'webroot'.DS.'swf'.DS.'cu3er.swf'; ?>, "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9", "<? print $this->webroot . 'swf/expressInstall.swf'?>", flashvars, attributes);
    swfobject.embedSWF("/var/www/stage4/app/View/Themed/MyTheme/webroot/swf/cu3er.swf, "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9", "/stage4/swf/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);

i want to get /var/www/stage4/app/webroot/swf